# How do I undo this git configuration?

Tags: git

I accidentally did:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

How do I undo this configuration item? Or reset it to default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually editing the global config file with

```
git config --global --edit
```

You can simply unset (remove) that particular setting with:

```
git config --global --unset url."https://".insteadOf
```

Note: you can see where each of your settings are defined with:

```
git config --show-origin -l
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into `~/.gitconfig` The `--global` flag will write to `~/.gitconfig`.

If you're on windows, the `.gitconfig` file should be stored on `C:/Users/<your profile name>`.

Answer (score 0):

Git has a mechanism for storing configuration in a text files.
Usually there are 3 levels for configuration:

> #### `--system`
>
> Usually you don't want to store any configuration here since it should contains OS specific configuration
>
> #### `--global`
>
> This is where your configuration should be.
>   This will generate `~/.gitconfig` file in your home directory on any OS. On widows the home directory is under `C:/Users/<your user>` and you can edit it with any text editor
>
> #### `--local`
>
> This is the default location when you set a configuration without specifying on which level to write this configuration to.

Git collect all the configuration in the following order and overwrite any existing value with the new value if it find one [system > global > local[.

In real life you should define global configuration like your default name & email in the global and if you wish to use different email for a specific project you can define it in a your local repository configuration.

Your configuration file will look something like:

[image]

So in your case you simply need to edit the **[global]** configuration file with any text editor and remove this line.